# Tunnel ports, thru VPS running OpenVPN, into my home network via Tomato Router

Tags: vpn, port-forwarding, openvpn, vps, tomato

Long-story-short, my ISP has me double-NAT'ed = I can't open ANY ports.

My router is running Tomato firmware, and I have its OpenVPN client linked to a VPS running OpenVPN. I can divert my home network's internet thru OpenVPN, thru the VPS, and everything seems to work.

BUT

I want to open ports, so I can get back into my network from outside: `3389` for Remote Desktop, `32400` for PLEX, my IP camera... All my stuff.

Can someone give me a "For Dummies" explanation how to do this?

Comment: BTW: My VPS is running CentOS-6

Answer (score 1):

My condolences on the double NAT.

If you have root access on the VPS, try using [destination port forwarding](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Security_Guide/s1-firewall-ipt-fwd.html) with iptables (DNATing). On the VPS, run the following commands

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1   #see link above to make this setting survive reboots
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 3389 -j DNAT --to-destination x.y.z.w
```

where eth0 is the internet-facing interface on the VPS, and `x.y.z.w` is the IP of your home computer *through the OpenVPN tunnel*. You may need to repeat the above commands with `-p tcp` replaced by `-p udp` if the service you are forwarding requires both TCP and UDP. If you have a default policy of DROP in your FORWARD chain (unlikely), you need something like
`iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -d x.y.z.w -j ACCEPT`

A completely different way to accomplish TCP port forwarding is to use `ssh` with the `-R` option. Issue the following command on your home computer

```
ssh -N -R *:3389:x.y.z.w:3389 user@m.n.o.p
```

where `x.y.z.w` is as above, `m.n.o.p` is the IP of your VPS, and `user` is your ssh login on the VPS. You need to set `GatewayPorts yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (and restart `sshd`) on the VPS.